# Показывать 4 дива один за другим ротация

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать показ дивов одним за другим в 4 строчки, верхний удаляется 
Вот что у меня получилось:

```js
var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
i = 0;
setInterval(function(e) {
  if (i > 6) {
    i = 0;
  }
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute("id", arr[i]);
  //$("#cont").append(div);
  document.getElementById("cont").appendChild(div);
  console.log(arr.length - i);
  //$( "#"+arr[arr.length - i] ).remove();
  if (i == 4) {
    $("#cont:first-child").remove;
  }
  $("#" + arr[i]).slideDown(1000);
  i++;
}, 5000);
```

```css
#one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: none
}

#three {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none
}

#four {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  display: none
}

#five {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont">

</div>
```

Comment: опишите словами, какое поведение вам требуется? У вас есть N-блоков данных, и максимум 4 позиции для отображения, и вы хотите чтобы там они по кругу бегали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, как мне кажется, нет большого смысла создавать и удалять блоки постоянно, если у них не меняется контент. Лучше изначально создать все блоки, и по таймеру управлять их видимостью.

```js
var ids = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
var i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    if($("#cont .block").length >= 4){
        $("#cont .block:first-child").remove();
    }
    
    var id = i++ % ids.length; 
    $('<div class="block"></div>')
            .attr("id", ids[id])
            .text(ids[id])
            .appendTo("#cont")
            .slideToggle(true);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
  display: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align:center;
}

#one { 
  background-color: red;  
}

#two {  
  background-color: blue;  
}

#three {  
  background-color: green;  
}

#four {
  background-color: black;
}

#five {  
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont">

</div>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, он хочет одновременно видеть только один блок?

Comment: хз, в заголовке написано "показывать 4 дива", а в тексте "показ дивов одним за другим в 4 строчки". ключевое вроде было "в 4 строчки", что я понял как "4 всегда должны быть видны"

Comment: хм.. возможно... но я слово "ротация" так понял, что надо один из 4 :)